# Hadoop2.2.0 can't visit the web http://<ip>:8088

Tags: hadoop

I setup a hadoop cluster with two nodes hadoop01(master- 10.0.0.151) and hadoop02(slaves- 10.0.0.152)
when a type start-dfs.sh and then visit website 
my_ip(just 10.0.0.151 above):50070. It's successful.
    But when i type start-yarn.sh then visit website my_ip:8088. It's failed.

my yarn-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
    <value>hadoop01:8032</value>
</property>        
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
    <value>hadoop01:8030</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
    <value>hadoop01:8031</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
    <value>hadoop01:8033</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
    <value>hadoop01:8088</value>
</property>
```

core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
     <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
     <value>hdfs://hadoop01:8020</value>
 </property>
 </configuration>
```

the same set as hadoop02(slave)

my hadoop01 hadoop-2.2.0/etc/hadoop/slaves set

```
hadoop01
hadoop02
```

After typing start-dfs.sh & start-yarn.sh then i type jps

```
hadoop01:
21594 NameNode
22345 NodeManager
22007 SecondaryNameNode
22171 ResourceManager
23147 Jps
21762 DataNode
hadoop02:
29861 NodeManager
30358 Jps
29665 DataNode
```

my /etc/hosts in hadoop01:

```
localhost       hadoop01
10.0.0.151      hadoop01
10.0.0.152      hadoop02
```

my /etc/hosts in hadoop02:

```
localhost       hadoop02
10.0.0.151      hadoop01
10.0.0.152      hadoop02
```

This bellow link is my yarn-nodemanager.log  I upload to google dirve
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7nCJ_XJWSrQN1BZVTVyOEgxd1E/edit?usp=sharing
    but yarn-nodemanager.log doesn't appear ERROR if i didn't miss some information..

Please help me improve the problem why I can't visit the website `http://10.0.0.151:8088`

**if need other information (such as hdfs-site.xml...etc) just tell me. I'll update..

```
netstat -tunalp | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50010           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17442/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50075           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17442/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50020           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17442/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50090           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17693/java
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.151:8020         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17267/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50070           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17267/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::13562                :::*                    LISTEN      21061/java
tcp6       0      0 10.0.0.151:8030         :::*                    LISTEN      20881/java
tcp6       0      0 10.0.0.151:8031         :::*                    LISTEN      20881/java
tcp6       0      0 10.0.0.151:8032         :::*                    LISTEN      20881/java
tcp6       0      0 10.0.0.151:8033         :::*                    LISTEN      20881/java
tcp6       0      0 :::33762                :::*                    LISTEN      21061/java
tcp6       0      0 :::8040                 :::*                    LISTEN      21061/java
tcp6       0      0 :::8042                 :::*                    LISTEN      21061/java
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 10.0.0.151:8088         :::*                    LISTEN      20881/java
```

After disable ipv6 , then i type netstat -tunalp | grep LISTEN

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:13562           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30608/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50010           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29967/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50075           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29967/java
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.151:8030         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30424/java
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.151:8031         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30424/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:52992           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30608/java
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.151:8032         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30424/java
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.151:8033         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30424/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50020           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29967/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8040            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30608/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8042            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30608/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50090           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30222/java
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.151:8020         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29790/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50070           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29790/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -  
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.151:8088         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30424/java
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Comment: Execute the command "netstat -tunalp | grep LISTEN" on your master node 10.0.0.151 and post the output

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here the problem is resouce manager is running, but the port(**8030,8031,8032,8033,8088**) occupied by resource manager uses tcp6 instead of tcp(see the left portion). You have two options either you can disable ipv6 in the linux system then restart yarn services.

or

Try modify your yarn-site.xml only on master node as follows. Don't modify the yarn-site.xml in slave nodes:

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
<configuration>
```

Specifying hostname causes the ports started as tcp6, even with out specifying those ports it would take the default value. Have a look at the following default ports

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml

After modiying yarn-site.xml restart your yarn-service

Comment: I disable ipv6 by add following three lines in hadoop01 & 02 at /etc/sysctl.conf <net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1> <net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1> <net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1> But I still can't visit the website 8088, i'll update the information after i disable ipv6 and type netstat -tunalp | grep LISTEN! I also try the method just modify hadoop01(master) yarn-site.xml, but it also can't work..

Comment: when i type hadoop command such as start-dfs.sh. It will appear this warn : Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable. I know this problem is hadoop version 32bit improper with 64 bits ubuntu.. But it just warn, i think it is nothing to do with my problem 'cannot visit web 8088'

Comment: And I try to establish vmware with ubuntu 12.04 32bits and hadoop-2.2.0 ,then i set up one node and it's successful to visit 50030 and 8088. But when i try again on my putty(my putty can connect to some vm) and just setup one node. it succeed in 50030 and fail in 8088...

Comment: (my original problem is setup on my putty's vm)

Answer (score 10):

the reason is you should change 10.0.0.151:8088 to 0.0.0.0:8088. the method is open the yarn-site.xml, add:

```
<property> 
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
  <value>0.0.0.0:8088</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the one that solved this issue for me

Answer (score 1):

For me this from [Hadoop: binding multiple IP addresses to a cluster NameNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25135183/hadoop-binding-multiple-ip-addresses-to-a-cluster-namenode):

> In hdfs-site.xml, set the value of dfs.namenode.rpc-bind-host to
>   0.0.0.0 and Hadoop will listen on both the private and public network interfaces allowing remote access and datanode access.

and opening 8088 in the firewall settings worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-605 ; Hadoop configuration scripts have added the `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` flag to force IPv4 binding, but this is missing from the Yarn configuration script. You can fix this by adding at the end of bin/yarn (before the exec):

> YARN_OPTS="$YARN_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"