# yarn + how to configure the resource-manager. web Appaddress

Tags: linux, hadoop, bigdata, port, hadoop-yarn

in yarn configuration , we have the following parameters ( according to https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.6/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml )

```
yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address             ${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8088   The http address of the RM web application.
yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.https.address       ${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8090   The https adddress of the RM web application.
yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address   ${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8031
```

we are not sure about how to set the `hostname`

for example

we can set the parameter:

`yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address` as

```
master01.formula45.com:8088        ( when master01.formula45.com is the hostname of the machine that resource manager is installed)
```

or maybe better as

```
0.0.0.0:8088
```

references:

https://superuser.com/questions/949428/whats-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-0-0-0-0
https://serverfault.com/questions/78048/whats-the-difference-between-ip-address-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1

Answer (score 1):

In *yarn-site.xml* set the following property:

```
 <property>
     <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
     <value>yourhostname</value>
 </property>
```

Your hostname (`yourhostname`) must be set to a valid IP in `/etc/hosts` file or be a valid host for your DNS.

Comment: I dont think so , see the post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23128593/hadoop2-2-0-cant-visit-the-web-http-ip8088  ( with the score 9 )

Comment: your question is confusing!